# Get data attribute on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the `data-attr` of the SELECTED `a` using jquery when the click handler is bound to it's outer div?

```
<ul class="js-click">
  <li><a href="" data-attr="hello">Hello</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-attr="world">World</a></li>
</ul>


$('.js-click').on('click', function(e) {

});
```

The restriction here is that I have to bind the click on the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the target `<a>` with `e.target` from the click event

```
$('.js-click').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var data = $(e.target).data("attr");
});
```

Comment: i would suggest checking for the target to make sure it is an anchor tag, else the answer would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.js-click').on('click','a', function(e) {
 var data=$(this).data('attr');
});
```

Listen for click on `anchor`

Answer (score 0):

```
//this would bind a handler that would execute anytime the ul is clicked
$('.js-click').on('click', function(e) { });
```

You're asking two questions.  How to bind a handler, and then how to access the data attribute.

**Binding the handler**

You're close to binding the handler to your `js-click` class, but you can get more granular by adding a filter.

[Refer to the jQuery docs for more info.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.js-click').on([event], [filter], [handler]);

//Bind a handler to js-click, but only execute for <a> elements
$('.js-click').on('click', 'a', function(e) { });
```

**Accessing that data attribute**

By including the `data-` prefix on the attribute, you're telling jQuery to cache the value automatically when it's ready.
[Refer to jQuery data docs for more info](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

`<a href="" data-attr="hello">Hello</a>`

would be equivalent to

```
$('a').data('attr', 'hello');
```

To access the data, you just need to use the key, which in this case would be `attr`.  It's worth noting that you *could* access the attribute directly, but use one or the other (preferably `.data`).

e.g. with your markup..
`<a href="" data-attr="hello">Hello</a>`

```
$('.js-click').on('click', 'a', function(e) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('attr', 'I changed');
    //what will the value be?  It's going to be 'Hello', because we're accessing the attribute in the DOM
    alert($this.attr('data-attr'));

    //what will the value be?  It's going to be 'I changed', because we're accessing the data cache
    alert($this.data('attr'));
});
```

Put them together and you can do this.

```
$('.js-click').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var data = $(this).data('attr');

    //quick sanity check to make sure the attribute exists
    if(typeof data !== 'undefined') {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```